# JAXB unmarshalling xml list element to single Kotlin object

Tags: java, kotlin, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have following XML to create nested Kotlin objects but it is not mapping all TimeCycleData element

```
<TimeCycle>
    <Last>
        <Date>2001-06-13T01:00:00.000Z</Date>
        <TimeCycleData>
            <Hours type="F">123</Hours>
        </TimeCycleData>
        <TimeCycleData>
            <Cycles>1234</Cycles>
        </TimeCycleData>
        <TimeCycleData>
            <Land>1234</Land>
        </TimeCycleData>
    </Last>
</TimeCycle>
```

and want to map following Kotlin data classes

```
data class TimeCycle(
        @field:XmlElement(name = "Last")
        val last: Last? = null
)

data class Last(

        @field:XmlElement(name = "Date")
        @field:XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = LocalDateTimeAdapter::class, type = LocalDateTime::class)
        val date: LocalDateTime? = null,

        @field:XmlElement(name = "TimeCycleData")
        val timeCycleData: TimeCycleData? = null
)

data class TimeCycleData(

        @field:XmlElement(name = "Hours")
        val hours: DurationDetails? = null,

        @field:XmlElement(name = "Cycles")
        val cycles: Int? = null,

        @field:XmlElement(name = "Land")
        val land: Int? = null
)

data class DurationDetails(

        @field:XmlValue
        @field:XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = DurationAdapter::class, type = Duration::class)
        val value: Duration? = null,

        @field:XmlAttribute(name = "type")
        val type: String = ""
)
```

when I unmarshal the XML, only the first `TimeCycleData` with `Hours` is filled. How can I merge all `TimeCycleData` into one single object?

**UPDATE:** corrected submitted xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess

```
        @field:XmlElement(name = "TimeCycleData")
        val timeCycleData: TimeCycleData? = null
```

should be declared in somehow this way

```
        @field:XmlElement(name = "TimeCycleData")
        @field:XmlElementWrapper(name = "TimeCycleInfo")
        val timeCycleInfo: List<TimeCycleData>? = null
```

.

Comment: sorry @nikolay i submitted wrong version of xml and corrected with valid one

Comment: @hrn, thank you for update.
Not sure at the moment how to implement it, probably, you may exclude `field:XmlElementWrapper` line from the code I suggested before.